# Imread an image from a .txt list

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am trying to read images in OpenCV C++ using `imread`. The issue here is the filename of the images. The filename contains a .dot in the name of the file. For example here is a sample of the names:

```
00006.jpg0.jpg
```

How is it possible to read such an image??
  vector files;

```
      string line;
      ifstream myfile ("Anny.txt");
      if (myfile.is_open())
      {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
           cout << line << '\n';
           files.push_back(line);
           string img  ="db/video/"+line;
           cout << img<< endl;
           string dest = "db/video1/"+line;
           Mat image = imread(img,1);

           cout << image.rows << " " << image.cols << endl;
           imshow("new", image);
           waitKey(0);
           imwrite( dest, image );

        }

        myfile.close();
      }
```

EDIT: basically the error lies with getline, but i dont get it. When I change img file and instead of +line put the printed string of line from terminal imshow and imread works like a charm.

Comment: no problem here. not even with 'my.png.jpg'

Comment: `cv::Mat image = cv::imread("00006.jpg0.jpg");` works fine for me

Comment: It seems that when I imread it  it return a empty mat file. When I am trying to imshow it as a result I am getting:
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /home/christosh/Desktop/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.7/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 269
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/christosh/Desktop/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.7/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:269: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow

Comment: rather assume a bad path then

Comment: does it work with different files/filenames? Maybe the image file isn't at the right location an no image is read at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread), `imread`:

> ... determines the type of an image by the content, not by the file extension.

If you're getting an error, it's not for the reason you have assumed it is. You need to better investigate whatever it is that you're seeing and haven't told us.

Comment: Shame on me, you are right!!

Answer (score 2):

Ok I ve changed the way that I read the txt file and everything works normal. Instead of getline I use infile and everything is working.

```
 ifstream infile("Anny.txt");
    string line;
    while(infile>> line){
        string img  ="db/video/"+line; //db/video/00006.jpg0.jpg
        cout << img<< endl;
        string dest = "db/video1/"+line;
        Mat image = imread(img,1);

        cout << image.rows << " " << image.cols << endl;
        imshow("new", image);
        waitKey(0);
        imwrite( dest, image );
    }
```